# Value getting lost on way to method

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I am still a beginner but trying to learn so probably doing something extremely silly. My question is about a simple Android calculator I am trying to make but I think the question concerns basic Java which I thought I understood. I get the value from the button that's pressed then pass it to a method to display the input then set a global variable for the input. The value in the method header is "1" if I press "1" but then gets lost in that method. Maybe I don't understand how to handle the Java types as I thought I did--don't know. I had the logic working at one time but had to change how it was displayed and that, of course, screwed up my logic somewhere. Anyway, I will post the passing statements and the receiving method for now. Thanks in advance.

```
  public void initButtons()
{
    //register buttons as listeners
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    final Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    final Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    final Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    final Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    final Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    final Button subButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subButton);
    final Button multButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multButton);
    final Button divButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divButton);
    final Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
    final Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);

    //when button is pressed, send num to calc function
    button1.setOnClickListener
    (new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                inputString = button1.getText().toString();
                displayCalc(inputString);
                //displayCalc(1.0);
            }
        }
    );

    private void displayCalc(String curValue)
{
    if (hasChanged = false)
    {
        //display number if reset
        String display = curValue;
        number1 = Double.parseDouble(display);
    }
    else                                                    
    {
    //  display = display + operator + curValue;
        //number2 = Double.parseDouble(curValue);
    }
    //showDisplay(display);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparisons in Java are made with double equal signs "==".

It is considered better form to test for booleans simply by putting them between the parentheses like this :

```
if(myBool){
    //do something
}
else if(!myOtherBool){
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have changed it. That's how it was originally but I changed for some reason. The value still isn't being convertd properly.When I debug, the value of my variable 'number1' is 0.0 if I push the '1' button. So it must be getting lost in the display variable because curValue ="1" but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't see what the problem could be if curValue is equal to "1" before you parse it.

Are you sure you are looking at the content of number1 after the parse operation while debugging?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Eclipse and was a little mixed up on how the debugging worked. I guess I was checking the value before it actually got assigned. But the answer still isn't ending up right so I will have to debug another method. Thanks for your help and sorry for the ignorant question! But at least I still learned something :)

Comment: Your'e welcome. Don't give up. We all have to start somewhere!